# android R.java: cannot resolve symbol in class id

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Hi I have been assigned to a new project on which someone else was working on earlier.. when i opened the project on my machine i get this error in R.java
I am unable to find any view with that name in my layout files

```
public static final int @+id/menu_tryAtHome=0x7f0d0483;
```

this is some error which I do not know how to fix... please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by searching for "menu_tryAtHome" using

```
ctrl+shift+r
```

searching like this i was able to find the xml error and i corrected it and then cleaned my project and rebuilded it.. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

R.java is automatically created and should not be edited. Do a clean and then try to run project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sanjeet.. I tried doing that and it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit the R.java file as it is auto-generated.Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

> `gradlew clean` and `gradlew build`

In Android Studio :

Build > Clean Project

Build > Rebuild Project